# Unable to return value back to CoroutineWorker when an exception is thrown

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutineworker

I'm having troubles using Coroutines in WorkManager. Here is the snippet of Worker class.

```
class ExampleWorker (context, workerParams) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

   override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      //set foreground
      try {
          val result = provider.getMeResult()

          if(result.success) return@withContext Result.success
          else return@withContext Result.failure()
      } catch(e: Exception) {
          handleErrors()
          return@withContext Result.failure()
      } finally {
        //clean up tasks
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the `getMeResult()`

```
class Provider {
   private val resultState = State()
   private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineHandler { _, throwable -> 
       //set result state to failed
       resultState.status = FAILED
       resultState.code = someErrorCode
   }
   private val runScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + exceptionHandler)
   private val jobsList = mutableListOf<Job>()

   suspend fun getMeResult(): State {
       val runJob = runScope.launch {
          someLongRunningTask() // spits result out to a channel, say itemsChannel
       }
       itemsChannel.consumeEach {
          //spawn a new coroutine to run the job concurrently
          val job = runScope.launch {
             somebackgroundTask() //Point A
          }

          jobsList.add(job)
       }
       //wait for all jobs to complete
       jobsList.joinAll()
   }
   //wait parent coroutine to complete
   runJob?.join()

   //once you reach here, looks everything has worked. Update run state to complete 
   resultState.status = COMPLETE

   return resultState
}
```

Ideally, this works as expected and result status is returned. However, whenever an error is thrown from Point A, exception handler receives the error and `getMeResult()` returns COMPLETE value. Worker catch block is never invoked, no error code was set. How can I make this work so that the Worker gets failed status when an error occurs? Also, when I cancel `runJob` within `exceptionHandler`, it fires multiple `CancellationException` with root cause as the actual exception type, but that cause is always `null` if I catch it within the parent Coroutine.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: If `//clean up tasks` is doing something blocking, that might cause the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right, but you literally set the status to `COMPLETE` before returning, potentially overwriting the `FAILED` status. However, even if not doing this, I believe you have race conditions here. I doubt we have guarantees the exception handler already executed at the time we return from the `getMeResult()`. Why not using a regular try..catch instead of an exception handler?

Comment: What is the reason to use that additional scope: `runScope`? You launch a coroutine in it and immediately wait for it. Would it make sense to run everything directly in the `getMeResult()`?

Comment: Thanks guys for the inputs. Yes, I think there are some adjustments needed to `getMeResult()`. Perhaps I could run a coroutine without an additional scope. Similarly, having a coroutine exception handler is no big help. I shall give it another try.